# InDesign server COM error

Tags: com, indesign-server

I am using InDesign server on windows. And developing application using Microsoft .Net web platform (ASP.NET).

I am generating Indd file using ImportXML() method provided by InDesign. I am getting following error randomly (sometimes more often):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x0000FFFF): Exception from HRESULT: 0x0000FFFF

   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)

   at InDesignServer.Document.ImportXML(String From)
```

There is no more information provided by InDesign about where it fails so am blocked there.

Can anyone help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time. But, I became active again on 'Stack'.
This was the error due to in-appropriate permission in DCOM config.
See steps below to check:
1. From the Start menu, click Run and type Dcomcnfg.exe
2. Select 'Computers'
3. Select 'My Computers'
4. DCOM Config
5. Find InDesign COM component and select properties
6. In this set appropriate security and identity.

COM exceptions are always vague, hard to answer by anyone!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ASP.NET, but in ExtendScript it is importXML (starts with low case and case-sensitive)

Also, check the file path you are passing to the importXML.

Make sure the document is created and initialised before you import xml